# Discord.js something-random-on-discord meme API not working: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am new to working with APIs in discord.js and I stumbled across a meme API in npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/something-random-on-discord). I followed the exact steps on the site and got this error:

```
/home/runner/Penguin69/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Penguin69/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/Penguin69/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/914839917769658371/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

my code was:

```
const random = require("something-random-on-discord").Random
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
 if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "!meme") {
 let data = await random.getMeme()
    message.channel.send(data)
  };
});
```

Does this have something to do with me using discord.js v13? If so, is there any other meme API/generator that works? Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found this other meme api: [`random-jokes-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-jokes-api)

It worked super well for me on my bot so it should work for you!

You would just use the following:

```
const Memer = require("random-jokes-api")

const Discord = require("discord.js")

const bot = new Discord.Client()

// Listen to the ready event
bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready!");  
})

// Listen to the message event
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content === "meme") {

        let meme = Memer.meme()

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(meme.title)
        .setImage(meme.url)
        .setFooter(`Categroy: ${meme.category}`)

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`something-random-on-discord`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/something-random-on-discord) does not support Discord.js v13!

There is a simple fix!

You can take the `image.url` option and put it in a new embed:

```js
const random = require("something-random-on-discord").Random.getMeme();

await message.channel.send({
   files: [random.embed.image.url]
});
```

Comment: How exactly should my code look like? Still can't get it to work.